# Render Layout Based on URL - ASP .NET MVC 6 Razor

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a page with a URL that starts with `/Plan/Production`. I am using the HTML5 History API, and when I click on a certain link, it will change the beginning of the URL to `/Plan/Selling`. This works great while clicking links and using the forward/back buttons, but when I refresh the page after the start of the URL changes to `/Plan/Selling`, it doesn't load a layout anymore. My solution was to edit my `_ViewStart.cshtml` file to check the beginning of the URL, and render a layout based on that, as seen in my code snippet below.

The problem is, if my URL begins with `/Plan/Selling`, it never even uses the `_ViewStart.cshtml` file. It only uses this file if the URL begins with `/Plan/Production`. Adding `console.logs` confirmed this. To be clear, the location of the file is `/Plan/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml`. Two examples of URLs I'm using are `https://localhost:44301/Plan/Selling/DetailsPPVS/1` (doesn't load a layout and never uses that ViewStart file), and `https://localhost:44301/Plan/Production` (Loads the proper layout and does use the ViewStart file).

How can I get `https://localhost:44301/Plan/Selling/DetailsPPVS/1` to use `/Plan/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml`?

Code from `/Plan/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml`:

```
<script>console.log("Plan/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml");</script>
@{
  if (Context.Request.Path.StartsWith("/Plan/Selling", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
  {
      <script>console.log("Pjax Layout");</script>
      Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_PjaxLayout.cshtml";
  }
  else {
      <script>console.log("Regular Layout (~/Areas/Plan/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml)");</script>
      Layout = "~/Areas/Plan/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`_ViewStart.cshtml` is not right place for this. try adding your code in `_Layout.cshtml`.